# I am trying to pass date object and other nested objects in query which is getting undefined in the search page

Tags: reactjs, next.js, router

```
//searchbar.tsx
import format from 'date-fns/format'
import moment from 'moment'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { DateRangePicker } from 'react-date-range'
import { FaBed } from 'react-icons/fa'
import { MdDateRange, MdOutlineEmojiPeople } from 'react-icons/md'
import styles from './Header.module.css'

interface options {
  adult: number
  children: number
  rooms: number
}

const SearchSection = () => {
  const [destination, setDestination] = useState('')
  const [openCalendar, setOpenCalendar] = useState(false)
  const router = useRouter()
  const [date, setDate] = useState<any>([
    {
      startDate: new Date(),
      endDate: new Date(),
      key: 'selection',
    },
  ])

  const [openOptions, setOpenOptions] = useState(false)
  const [options, setOptions] = useState<any>({
    adult: 1,
    children: 0,
    rooms: 1,
  })

  const { adult, children, rooms } = options

  const handleOption = (name: string, operation: string) => {
    setOptions((prevState: options) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: operation === 'i' ? options[name] + 1 : options[name] - 1,
    }))
  }

  const handleSearch = () => {
    const searchOptions = {
      destination,
      date,
      options,
    }

    console.log(searchOptions) //(it's all properties are filled as intended)
    //passing this data to the /search page in the query
    router.push({ pathname: '/search', query: searchOptions })
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.headerSearch}>
      <div className={styles.headerSearchItem}>
        <FaBed className={styles.headerIcon} />
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Where are you going"
          className={styles.searchInput}
          value={destination}
          onChange={(e) => setDestination(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      <div className={styles.headerSearchItem}>
        <MdDateRange className={styles.headerIcon} size={20} />
        <span
          className={styles.headerSearchText}
          onClick={() => setOpenCalendar((prevState) => !prevState)}
        >
          {`${format(date[0].startDate as any, 'MM/dd/yy')}`} to{' '}
          {`${format(date[0].endDate as any, 'MM/dd/yy')}`}
        </span>
        {openCalendar && (
          <DateRangePicker
            ranges={date}
            onChange={(ranges) => {
              setDate([ranges.selection])
            }}
            editableDateInputs={false}
            className={styles.date}
            //this is to disable all dates before today
            minDate={moment().toDate()}
          />
        )}
      </div>

      <div className={styles.headerSearchItem}>
        <MdOutlineEmojiPeople className={styles.headerIcon} size={20} />
        <span
          className={styles.headerSearchText}
          onClick={() => setOpenOptions((prevState) => !prevState)}
        >
          {adult} adults {children} chilren {rooms} room{' '}
        </span>
        {openOptions && (
          <div className={styles.options}>
            <div className={styles.optionItem}>
              <span className="optionText">Adult</span>

              <div className={styles.counter}>
                <button
                  className={styles.counterBtn}
                  onClick={() => handleOption('adult', 'i')}
                >
                  +
                </button>
                <span className={styles.countNumber}>{adult}</span>
                <button
                  className={styles.counterBtn}
                  onClick={() => handleOption('adult', 'd')}
                  disabled={adult <= 1}
                >
                  -
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.optionItem}>
              <span className="optionText">Children</span>
              <div className={styles.counter}>
                <button
                  className={styles.counterBtn}
                  onClick={() => handleOption('children', 'i')}
                >
                  +
                </button>
                <span className={styles.countNumber}>{children}</span>
                <button
                  className={styles.counterBtn}
                  onClick={() => handleOption('children', 'd')}
                  disabled={children < 1}
                >
                  -
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.optionItem}>
              <span className="optionText">Rooms</span>
              <div className={styles.counter}>
                <button
                  className={styles.counterBtn}
                  onClick={() => handleOption('rooms', 'i')}
                >
                  +
                </button>
                <span className={styles.countNumber}>{rooms}</span>
                <button
                  className={styles.counterBtn}
                  onClick={() => {
                    handleOption('rooms', 'd')
                  }}
                  disabled={rooms <= 1}
                >
                  -
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>

      <div className={styles.headerSearchItem}>
        <button className={styles.headerBtn} onClick={handleSearch}>
          Search
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default SearchSection


//searchpage.tsx
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const Search = () => {
  const router = useRouter()

  const {
    query: { destination, date, options },
  } = router

  console.log(destination, date, options)

   //here I am getting "undefined" or nothing for date and options
  return (
    <div className="search">
      <div className="searchWrapper">
        <div className="searchOption">
          <h1 className="searchTitle">Search</h1>
          <div className="searchOption">
            <label>Destination</label>
            <input type="text" />
          </div>
          <div className="searchOption">
            <label>Check-in Date</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="searchResult">a</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Search
```

I am trying to pass the selected date and options as you can see in the nextjs router query while pushing to the "/search page". The searchOptions that I passed has all it's properties filled while pushing. But the query only has destination property filled, and other date and options field are undefined. I don't know why does query only accepts simple kind of object and doesn't allow array of objects and nested objects?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `stringify` your value before push to router and at search page, you need to `parse` you params

```
//searchbar.tsx
const searchOptions = {
    destination,
    date: JSON.stringify(date),
    options: JSON.stringify(options),
}
router.push({ pathname: '/search', query: searchOptions })

//searchpage.tsx
const {
    query: { destination },
} = router

const date = JSON.parse(router.query.date);
const options = JSON.parse(router.query.options);
```

Hope it help!!